# Sorting algorithm doesn't work

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

I'm trying to spiff-up my skills and thought I would try to write my own little sorting algorithm:

```
import random
from random import randint

int_list = []
for i in range(10):     #Creates a 10-entry list of randon ints
    int_list.append(random.randint(0,10))
print "Unsorted list:\t" + str(int_list)

def sorter(int_list):
    for i in range(len(int_list)-1):
        while int_list[i] > int_list[i+1]:
            temp = int_list[i]
            int_list[i] = int_list[i+1]
            int_list[i+1] = temp
            continue
        return int_list

print "\"Sorted\" list:\t" + str(sorter(int_list))
```

When I run this script it only sorts the first two entries of the list. My understanding of `continue` was that it would keep looping through my while loop while the `while` statement was `True`.

Comment: Actually, since it is at the end of the while-loop, the `continue` is doing nothing.  You can (should) remove it no problem.

Comment: Should it be at the beginning of the loop, or not in it at all?

Comment: `continue` just stops the execution of the current iteration and starts the next.

Comment: As a side not you don't need a `temp` variable to swap two values, simply do:    `int_list[i], int_list[i+1] = int_list[i+1], int_list[i]` :)

Comment: @Matt - In addition to the answers, I think you could use a reference on [`continue`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` actually operates like an `if`, looks like you're trying to [*bubble-sort*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) and you're not implementing it correctly (you should keep iterating until the iteration doesn't preform swap even once) - which is why you don't really sort.

Second, the pythonic way to "swap" is not:

```
temp = int_list[i]
int_list[i] = int_list[i+1]
int_list[i+1] = temp
```

but rather:

```
int_list[i], int_list[i+1] = int_list[i+1], int_list[i]
```

Comment: In regards to the 'pythonese', if you will, at the end of your answer: Does that work like `int_list[i] = int_list[i+1]` and `int_list[i+1] = int_list[i]` effectively equating the first entry on the left side with the first entry on the right? Aka: Could I utilize the same structure with an `n`-length equality statement (rather than the 2-length shown above)?

Comment: @Matt why won't you try ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `return int_list` statement is indented too far - it is within the `for` loop, so your function quits at the end of the first iteration.

Also,

```
int_list = []
for i in range(10):     #Creates a 10-entry list of randon ints
    int_list.append(random.randint(0,10))
```

could be reduced to

```
int_list = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(10)]
```

and the `while` is only ever going to run 0 or 1 times (you can just use `if`).

Also, it looks like you are just doing the *first pass* of a bubble sort - it will move the highest value to the end of the list, but will not result in a completely sorted list. You need another `for` loop to do this repeatedly ('bubbling up' values).